# htaccess rule doesn't work

Tags: regex, .htaccess

this is my original link

```
http://localhost/xx/xx/public_html/news.php?id=7
```

i want to change it to

```
http://localhost/xx/xx/public_html/news-7-TitleOfNews.html
```

here is my htaccess

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 www.site.com/404.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news-([0-9]*)(?:-([0-9a-zA-Z*]))?(?:\.html)?$ news.php?id=$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work (redirect to 404 page )

Comment: Have you got `Mod_rewrite` active on server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for this:

```
RewriteRule ^news-([0-9]*)(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]*)?(?:\.html)?$ news.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The difference is that `*` quantifier should be outside of the character class expression. And wrapping the single character class into parentheses is redundant.